# Await task not returning

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, openai-api

Calling OpenAI for v1/Chat/Completions, my code posts but does not return.
Using Fiddler, I do see the returned values, so the POST appears to be working.

```
public async Task SendQueryToChatGPT(string question)
{
    string result = "No error";

    string apiKey = OPENAI_API_KEY;
    string apiUrl = OPENAI_CHAT_URL;

    string prompt = question;

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {apiKey}");

        var requestBody = new
        {
            model = cbModel.SelectedValue,
            messages = new[]
            {
                new
                {
                    role = "user",
                    content = prompt
                }
            }
        };

        txtResponse.InnerText = "Getting Answer...";

        try
        {
            var response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestBody), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                dynamic jsonResponse = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(responseBody);
                string aiResponse = jsonResponse.choices[0].message.content;
                                   
                result = aiResponse;
                
            }
            else
            {
                result = response.ReasonPhrase;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = ex.Message;
        }
        

        // Display  
        txtResponse.InnerText = result;
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Result: " + result);

    return;
}
```

And here is a reply as seen with Fiddler:
The question was: "The Rain in Spain falls where?"
{
"id": "chatcmpl-8p28kGpDIpr7a7yiyL6kQeew389sg",
"object": "chat.completion",
"created": 1707173646,
"model": "gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
"choices": [
{
"index": 0,
"message": {
"role": "assistant",
"content": "The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain."
},
"logprobs": null,
"finish_reason": "stop"
}
],
"usage": {
"prompt_tokens": 14,
"completion_tokens": 10,
"total_tokens": 24
},
"system_fingerprint": null
}

I'm writing for ASP.NET C# winforms. In the default.aspx page I do have

```
   <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" Async="true".....
```

Comment: Did you set `aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` to `True` in Web.config?

Comment: I tried and it made no difference.

Comment: You might be experiencing a deadlock. Look for other StackOverflow questions about using `await` in classic ASP.NET and setting up a single-threaded synchronization context.